# How todo a choose file upload button that previews the file chosen without using a upload button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor-pages

I'm trying to todo were the user uploads a excel file and then get a preview of the excel before submitting it. I want to convert the excel to a html table.

Comment: If you invoke your C# code, ie your server, you're submitting the whole file. But if you process it locally with Javascript and do a preview, you end up rendering an HTML table or something like that. Choose one or the other, but the file should appear somewhere.

Comment: Well, you have to let the file up-load. At that point you can crack open the Excel file and pull some data - but not with formatting. You can't really do anything client side - in fact you can't even write js code (or server side) code to select a file or even touch a file. Since if you could, then while you come to my site to look at cat pictures, I will be rumanging around on your hard drive looking for banking files, ,or files called passwords and start to pull them. So, you can upload the file only based on user selection. Once done, you can display parts of it with some confirm button.